# ERROR: date/time field value out of range in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, csv, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have an CSV file with ASCII encoding generated from Oracle Stored Procedure.

I need to import CSV file into Postgres DB table using stored procedure where in postgres by default `set date to MDY`

I did try to `set datestyle to SQL,DMY;` in postgres terminal last night.

Today morning when i see the datastyle format its MDY format.Until unless its configured in postgres.conf file but i don't need it there because it is applicable to all Databases.

So I need to set datestyle at the time of importing CSV file in stored procedure

Here is the script at Postgres

```
begin
    set schema 'public';
    raise notice 'CSV PATH: %,TABLE NAME: %',csv_path,target_table;
   execute format('truncate %I ',target_table);
    execute format('copy %I from %L WITH (FORMAT csv)',target_table, csv_path);
    return;
end;
```

Comment: I rolled back to previous version, because you did not edit it - you asked a new question. please ask a new to do so

Comment: Here is the link to set the datestyle permanently https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19679/how-to-set-postgresql-database-to-see-date-as-mdy-permanently

Comment: "So I need to set datestyle at the time of importing CSV file in stored procedure" ?..

Comment: I thought that in different approach which is not accurate better to go with database command

Answer (score 2):

to set config for transaction use `local`. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html

> **SESSION**  is the default if neither SESSION nor LOCAL appears

(bold mine)

so example:

```
t=# begin;
BEGIN
t=# set local DateStyle to ISO,DMY;
SET
t=# show DateStyle;
 DateStyle
-----------
 ISO, DMY
(1 row)
t=# end;
COMMIT
t=# show DateStyle;
 DateStyle
-----------
 ISO, MDY
(1 row)
```

also mind how you set DateStyle - it is pair of values.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html

> DateStyle (string)
>
> Sets the display format for date and time values, as well as the rules
>   for interpreting ambiguous date input values. For historical reasons,
>   this variable contains two independent components: the output format
>   specification (ISO, Postgres, SQL, or German) and the input/output
>   specification for year/month/day ordering (DMY, MDY, or YMD). These
>   can be set separately or together. The keywords Euro and European are
>   synonyms for DMY; the keywords US, NonEuro, and NonEuropean are
>   synonyms for MDY. See Section 8.5 for more information. The built-in
>   default is ISO, MDY, but initdb will initialize the configuration file
>   with a setting that corresponds to the behavior of the chosen lc_time
>   locale.